# Determine if a string contains 3 words in order from each of 3 word arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement

How can I test a string to see if it contains a single word each, in order, from three arrays of words? I want `true` to be printed in the console when the test string `message` (see below) contains words, in order, from the three arrays. The first word in order should be any of the words in the `first_word` array. The second word should be any word in the `second_word` array, and the same for the third word from the `third_word` array. The words will always be separated by a single space, and no other separator character(s).

The words should be detected anywhere within the test string (i.e. there can be any contents prior to, or after the words). It should still print `true` if there is something before or after the elements from `first_word`, `second_word`, and `third_word`.

This is what I currently have:

```
var message = '';
var first_word  = ['nice',  'cool', 'awesome'];
var second_word = ['red',   'blue', 'green'];
var third_word  = ['apple', 'pear', 'mango'];

if (message.includes(first_word + ' ' + second_word + ' ' + third_word)) {
   console.log(true);
}
```

Test cases that should occur:

```
message = 'nice blue mango'                  // true
message = 'red nice apple'                   // false (not in order)
message = 'red nice apple, nice green apple' // true (contains words in order somewhere in string)
message = 'nice red'                         // false (does not contain third word)
message = 'nice very blue mango'             // false (there is a word in-between)
```

The third example is true because nice green apple are elements from the array in the right order.

Comment: Is it that for the third example, it should return true because of the `nice green apple` at the end? Meaning that the words have to be consecutive to be valid?

Comment: Yes the third example is true because `nice green apple` are elements from the array in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) generated from your word arrays

In my opinion, the easy way to do this is to generate a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (RegExp) from your word arrays. Then use that RegExp to test for the sequence of words that you desire.

```js
//Create the RegExp
regExp = new RegExp([first_word, second_word, third_word].map(list => '(?:' + list.join('|') + ')').join(' '));
//Check the test cases
testCases.forEach(message => console.log(regExp.test(message)));
```

```html
<!-- Setup from question -->
<script>
    let testCases = [
        'nice blue mango',                  // true
        'red nice apple',                   // false (not in order)
        'red nice apple, nice green apple', // true
        'nice red',                         // false (does not contain third word)
        'nice very blue mango',             // false (there is a word in-between)
        'lol nice blue mango',              // true (additional, from OP's comment)
    ];

    var first_word  = ['nice',  'cool', 'awesome'];
    var second_word = ['red',   'blue', 'green'];
    var third_word  = ['apple', 'pear', 'mango'];
</script>
```

#### What this does

Breaking this down, what this does is first create an array containing the arrays of words for which we are searching:

```js
[first_word, second_word, third_word]
```

Results in:

```json
[
    ["nice","cool","awesome"],
    ["red","blue","green"],
    ["apple","pear","mango"]
]
```

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is then called to map that array into an array of the regular expression text for each set of words. [`.join('|')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is used to concatenate all of the words in a list into one string with the words separated by `|`.

```js
[first_word, second_word, third_word].map(list => '(?:' + list.join('|') + ')')
```

Results in:

```json
[
    "(?:nice|cool|awesome)",
    "(?:red|blue|green)",
    "(?:apple|pear|mango)"
]
```

These are then [`.join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ed into one string with spaces separating each list. This results in:

```
(?:nice|cool|awesome) (?:red|blue|green) (?:apple|pear|mango)
```

which is the string used to create the regular expression, using [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax). The regular expression is then used to [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) each `message` string to see if the specified words are in the desired order.

#### Possibly slower than other, more complex solutions

While easy, using a RegExp may not be the highest performance method for obtaining the result. If you're testing *huge* numbers of strings, then you *might* want to look into improving performance by using an alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var message = 'lol nice red apple';
    var first_word = ['nice', 'cool', 'awesome'];
    var second_word = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
    var third_word = ['apple', 'pear', 'mango'];
    
    var messages = message.trim().split(',');
    var splitMessage = null;
    var resultCount = 0;
    var startFrom = 0;
    
    messages.forEach(function(msg){
      splitMessage = msg.trim().split(' ');
      
      while(!first_word.includes(splitMessage[startFrom])){
        startFrom++;
      }
      
    if(first_word.includes(splitMessage[startFrom]) && second_word.includes(splitMessage[startFrom + 1]) && third_word.includes(splitMessage[startFrom + 2])){
     resultCount++;
    }

    })
    
    console.log(resultCount === messages.length)
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the test for the 3rd example.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does everything as I wanted, but if you add something in the beginning it would print as false. I need it to print true even when something is in front of first word for example if `message = 'lol nice blue mango' //true`. Do you think you will be able to do that?